# why API Validation for multipart/form-data not working in anypoint studio 6?

Tags: multipartform-data, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, raml

In design center, all the validation works successfully like text field is missing file attached is not JSON format but in studio 6, all these validations failed.

Can anybody answer why this happen and how to fix this?

Sample API given below:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Sample API
/content:
 post:
  body:
   multipart/form-data:
    properties:
     text: string
     file1:
      type: file
      fileTypes: ['application/json']
     file2:    
      type: file    
      fileTypes: ['text/html']
```

Answer (score 0):

Studio 6 has an older RAML parser that may not be compatible with this RAML. Design Center and Studio 7.5.x have more modern parsers. It is possible that the older parser can not handle multipart/form-data correctly.

Comment: In 7.5.x it has thrown error if file1 is not present but it is accepting png file also where as ideally it should only accept .json file

Comment: The RAML is just one part of the issue. Please share the HTTP request, without the binary details of the file. You could enable HTTP wire logging to print the request in the log: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging